# How to delete Azure table entities based on range query results

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Am trying to delete Azure table entities based on my range filter. All am trying here is to delete the older records.

I was able to get the correct entites based on my range search condition.

```
TableQuery<Tables> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<Tables>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "DeleteTablename"),
    TableOperators.And,
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("StartedOn", QueryComparisons.LessThan, DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, -60, 0)))));

    foreach(Tables rows in logTable.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery)) {
        log.Info($"{rows.PartitionKey}, {rows.RowKey}\t{rows.FinishedOn}\t{rows.Timestamp}");
    }
    //till here it works
    TableResult retrievedResult = logTable.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery);
    Tables deleteEntity = (Tables)retrievedResult.Result;
```

am getting following errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult'    timertest
>
> Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult'
>   to 'timertest.Tables' timertest

Notes:

- `timertest` is my `namespace`
- `Tables` is a class, that extends `TableEntity` class to add my
  custom proporties in azure table.

Any ideas to delete entities based on range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas to delete entities based on range?

In Azure Tables to perform bulk delete, you will need to use `Entity Group Transaction` and add the entities that you wish to delete in a batch and then execute that batch operation. For entities to be manipulated (create, update or delete) in a batch:

- They should have the same `PartitionKey` value.
- A maximum of 100 entities can be included in a batch.
- Maximum payload size of a batch can be 4MB.

Please note that even if one entity fails in the group transaction, the entire transaction is rolled back.

You can learn more about entity batch transaction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions.

Comment: Thanks. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: Couldn't understand how to use `Entity Group Transaction` in my code. Sorry am very new to c# & azure, would you mind writing a small example.